# Failed to import dashboard to Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I'm new to kibana. I exported a dashboard from one kibana account, then I'm trying to import the dashboard to another kibana account. The import failed with message "Sorry, there's an error. The file could not be processed." the dashboard is a NDJSON file. Is there anyway to solve it? I even don't know how to check details of the error like checking stack trace in IDE.

note: I found I exported the dashboard from kibana 7.5.1, and the kibana I'm trying to import this dashboard is 7.2.0. Is that caused by version incompatibility?

[image]

[image: failed to import dashboard]

[image]

Comment: Can you open your browser's developer tools and maybe you can see some red message there and share it?

Comment: @Val added it. That's what I can find in develop tool console. Not sure how find further detail

Comment: Try to go to the next work tab, click on the red call(s) that fails and try to extract the request and response payload